# Display the exact value of a field in Kibana panel

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using `NATS` in my project and I am trying to display [its monitoring data](https://docs.nats.io/nats-server/configuration/monitoring) in a `Kibana` panel. What I need is to display number of connections connected to each server. The raw data for a server is like this:

```
{
  "server_id": "NACDVKFBUW4C4XA24OOT6L4MDP56MW76J5RJDFXG7HLABSB46DCMWCOW",
  "now": "2019-06-24T14:28:16.520365-07:00",
  "num_connections": 25,
  "total": 25,
  "offset": 0,
  "limit": 1024,
  "connections": [
    {
      "cid": 1,
      "ip": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 49764,
      "start": "2019-06-24T14:27:25.94611-07:00",
      "last_activity": "2019-06-24T14:27:25.954046-07:00",
      "rtt": "275µs",
      "uptime": "50s",
      "idle": "50s",
      "pending_bytes": 0,
      "in_msgs": 0,
      "out_msgs": 0,
      "in_bytes": 0,
      "out_bytes": 0,
      "subscriptions": 1,
      "name": "NATS Sample Subscriber",
      "lang": "go",
      "version": "1.8.1",
      "subscriptions_list": [
    "hello.world"
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

What I need is a chart which shows `num_connections` of each server; a simple line chart is fine.

I have tried `Count` and `Unique Count` of `connections.cid`, but it won't show the correct value. The only ways that comes into my mind to achieve my needs are either showing the exact value of `num_connections` or displaying the length of `connections`; but I'm not sure if there are any possible ways to do this in `Kibana`.

BTW, index is a simple `nats-connz*` wildcard without any time filed.

Comment: Hi, @Zeinab, have you checked my answer? Was it helpful?

Comment: Sorry for late response @glenacota. I checked it and it was very helpful, I learned a lot; but the issue has been solved by using `TopHit`.

Answer (score 1):

if by a Kibana panel you mean a [visualization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/visualize.html) that you could add to a dashboard, then you might consider using [Lens](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/lens.html). What you would need to do is to

1. Go to `Kibana > Visualize`
2. Click on the `Create Visualization` button, and then click on `Lens`
3. Select the `nats-connz*` index pattern from the dropdown (if you haven't created an index pattern yet, [do that first](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns.html))
4. Drag the `now` field from the left column and drop it into the central area
5. Drag the `num_connections` field from the left column and drop it into the central area
6. Select the `Line` type of visualization from the dropdown menu

If your version of Kibana doesn't include Lens, you can

1. Go to `Kibana > Visualize`
2. Click on the `Create Visualization` button, and then click on [TSVB](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.9/TSVB.html)
3. In the `Panel Options` tab, type `nats-connz*` into the `Index pattern` field (if you haven't created an index pattern yet, [do that first](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns.html)), then set `now` into the `Time Field` field
4. In the `Data` panel, set the `Max` aggregation for the `num_connections` field

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by using the `TopHit` aggregator.